# How to achieve uniform thickness with no breaks when extruding faces?

Tags: modeling, mesh

Why is it that when I extrude individual faces, I am getting border with a discontinued profile at the corners (see picture)?

Is there any way to make the border continuous with uniform thickness around a given object "P".

[image: Extrude menu]

[image: Result with problems at A]

Answer (score 6):

If you extrude individual faces these faces will not be connected anymore. This is why you get discontinuities.

Extrude your faces by pressing <kbd>E</kbd> instead (this is equal to `Extrude and Move on Normal`). Then immediatly press <kbd>Rmb</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> to cancel the translation. now the extruded faces should be at the same location as the previous faces.

To get walls with an even thickness use `Shrink/Fatten` by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>. By moving your mouse you can change the thickness of your walls. To get even thickness independent of corner angles hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key while moving the mouse. If you are satisfied press <kbd>Lmb</kbd> to apply the tranformation.